# Visual Studio Code - Searching triggers Windows Defender process with high CPU usage

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to move from Netbeans IDE to VS Code. I have a fresh instalation (newest version 1.29.0) without any extensions on Windows 8.1.

When I try to search a file by CTRL+E immedietly **Antimalware Service Executable** process (Windows Defender) spikes CPU usage for a second and my CPU fan goes nuts. Even before I type to search anything. It's very annoying.

I have excluded code.exe from Windows Defender and the entire folder within I'm trying to search. It helped a little - **98% CPU usage** lowered to like 40%. Still not the result I was hoping for.

CPU is Intel Core i7-2600.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is a bug in VS code.  A couple of issues have been raised about it on GitHub in the last few days:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63070